# how to make a div slide into position

Tags: jquery, draggable

i have a div and within that one is multiple divs that are draggable, so how do i make so when the user drags the first div the remaining ones slide into it's place

thanks

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `sortable`... http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADD Draggable and sortable

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#sortable

Comment: i think sortable is for dragging and dropping within a specific space but what i am trying is to make the divs slide in place of the dragged out div"that can be placed anyware"