# Make a div slide into new height when changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've looked around for the answer to my question, I looked at [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439686/how-to-make-a-div-slide-into-position) as well as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17355675/how-to-make-a-div-slide-into-place-jquery), though they explain a different want to the meaning "slide into position."

What I'm wanting to achieve is when a **div**'s height changes, it slides into its new position.

Say I have a static height of `50px`, like:

```
#footer {
  height: 50px !important;
}
```

Then I change that using **jQuery**:

```
$('#footer').height(100);
```

Currently, when those two are loaded, it's a weird instant change, I'm looking for say the `slideDown` motion where the div just falls into the new height instead of changing instantly.

I know this can be done using CSS since I've done this before (but I can't find the souce code) whereas the change example `80%` width will change as the page moves (though if you have jQuery/JS solutions I don't mind).

Thanks!

Comment: `#footer { transition: height .5s; }`?

Comment: Wow.. Thanks so much :P That's the style! @MichaelCoker

Comment: While I'd encourage you to use CSS, you could also modify your jQuery: `$('#footer').animate({height: '100px'}, 1000, 'easeInOut');`

Comment: I'm comfortable with jQuery but CSS just gives that whole no need for an event handler feel, so I think I'll go with CSS @cale_b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>**[Michael Coker!](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1123505/michael-coker)** I'm doing this solely to so that the question could be marked as being completed. I encourage you to post your answer and get the credit for it. If you do, I'll gladly delete mine. Until then...</sup>

You got to update your style with a `transition` and remove the `!important`:

```
#footer {
  height: 50px; /* Remove !important or it'll override jQuery */
  /* and for older broswer support */
  -webkit-transition: height .5s;
  -moz-transition: height .5s;
  -o-transition: height .5s;
  transition: height .5s;
}
```

for it to smoothly work with `$('#footer').height(100);`

Example:

```js
$('#footer').height(100);
```

```css
#footer {
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  /* And for older broswer support */
  -webkit-transition: height .5s;
  -moz-transition: height .5s;
  -o-transition: height .5s;
  transition: height .5s;
  transition: height .5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

As [cale_b](https://stackoverflow.com/users/870729/cale-b) also noted, this could also be accomplished as:

```js
$('#footer').animate({height: '100px'}, 500);

//Because jQuery doesn't support 'easeInOut', you'll need jQuery UI to support it. I just omitted it from this example.
```

```css
#footer {
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Comment: I'll up vote for now and give it some time just in case Michael comes back :')